Report Server with dynamic configuration to connect to different Database on different servers
We are using SSRS as of now. very old one 2008 and we have thousands of reports done for our different clients. we have 5 different server having different DBs as per clients. as of now we using client side reporting.
We wanted to move to Server side Reporting to have dedicated Reporting Server and all reports will be there and wanted dynamically have reporting server to connect DBs. so that all the Clients can access reports only from reporting server. we do not have to copy on each client servers.
Is there any way in Microsoft or Telerik we wanted to move from old SSRS.
Can i get an update or some information on same. as possible we wanted to remain in SSRS new version if dynamic connection possible from server side reporting or else we have to move Telerik or so. in case Telerik we have to even do all reports from scratch. Which will be extremely difficult.
Can any one have knowledge on SSRS higher version if Server side reporting possible with dynamic connection.

It's not clear what setup you intend to have after your upgrade. Maybe draw a simple diagram with the database(s) and report server(s) listed along with a few examples of users. It is possible to have a dynamic datasource that could set to point to a specific database, based on the user.

Hello, actually we wanted to know SSRS now we are using very old one 2008, if we upgrade can we have separate reporting Server with dynamic connection made to different DBs.  we have 4 servers each servers have different client DBs. we should have dynamic way to connect to them not like now we have reporting on client side.  like on reporting server there should be ability to connect DB dynamically to fetch data to show in report to individual Clients.

This post gives you a roadmap for what you need:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4302/implement-dynamic-data-sources-in-sql-server-reporting-services/
The solution is essentially:

table DatabaseServers in a common database that lists the servers (they use msdb)
report parameter to select a server
expression for the connection string for the client databases

For your scenario, you may want to constrain the users to a single entry for the list of servers from the table DatabaseServers, so you can hide that parameter. Lots of ways to achieve that, SQL row-level security might be the best:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver16

Thank you so much for reply. i will go through in details. our main concern was since we have thousands of standard and custom reports for clients, it would have been too much work if we are moving away from SSRS. like Telerik, we had to start all reports also in scratch. which is next to impossible to do how easily we can use SSRS now. since we are using SSRS 2008 which also very old we have to move to higher version but keeping mind SSRS should support dynamic way of connecting to diff. DBs. Thank you again will go though in detail.
